# How to find a string then find the sum of all cells next to the found string

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

[image]

So I'm trying to get G4 to automatically find "Bananas" in all of C and for every time it finds a value it adds up the corresponding number in D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(C4:D, "select C,sum(D) where C <>'' group by C label sum(D)''")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=SUMIF(C$4:C, F4, D$4:D)
```

[image: 0]